# Byte ordering for multibyte characters in SQL Server versus Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, encoding, unicode, hashing

I am currently in the process of migrating data from Oracle to SQL Server and I'm encountering an issue trying to validate the data post-migration.

Environment Details:

- Oracle 12 - AL32UTF8 character set
- Client - NLS_LANG - WE8MSWIN1252
- VARCHAR2 field

SQL Server 2016

- Latin1_General_CI_AS collation
- NVARCHAR field

I'm using DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH on Oracle to generate a checksum of the whole row, then copying to SQL and using HASHBYTES to generate a checksum of the whole row, which I'm then comparing to validate the data matches.

The checksums match for all rows, except those with multibyte characters.

For example, rows with this character: ◦ do not match in the checksums, even though the data is transferred correctly. When I use DUMP in Oracle or convert to VARBINARY in SQL Server the data matches exactly except for the bytes for this character.

In SQL Server, the bytes are 0xE625 and in Oracle they are 0x25E6.

Why are they ordered differently, and is there a reliable way to convert one to the other to ensure the checksum at the other end matches for strings with multi-byte characters?

Comment: Please provide the hashing algorithm used, as well as the exact `DUMP` command. The more details you provide the better, as I had to do a lot of guessing so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The collation of an `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` / `NTEXT` column has no bearing on the encoding used to store the data in that column. `NVARCHAR` data is *always* UTF-16 Little Endian (LE). The collation of `NVARCHAR` data only impacts sorting and comparison. Collation does impact the encoding of `VARCHAR` data since the collation determines the code page used to store the data in that column / variable / literal, but we aren't dealing with that here.

As [sepupic mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229145/30859), what you are seeing when you view the data in binary form is a difference in endianness (Oracle is using Big Endian while SQL Server is using Little Endian). HOWEVER, what you are seeing when you view the binary form of the string in Oracle is *not* how the data is actually being stored. You are using `AL32UTF8` which is UTF-8, which encodes that character in 3 bytes, not 2, as: `E2, 97, A6`.

Also, it is not possible for the hashes to be the same for rows of just "a" but not when they include "◦", not unless the hashing in Oracle was done without conversion, hence using the UTF-8 encoding, and the hashing in SQL Server accidentally converting to `VARCHAR` first. Otherwise there is no hash algorithm that will behave as you are describing, as you can verify by running the following in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Algorithm NVARCHAR(50) = N'MD4';
SELECT HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x3100), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x0031);
SET @Algorithm = N'MD5';
SELECT HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x3100), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x0031);
SET @Algorithm = N'SHA1';
SELECT HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x3100), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x0031);
SET @Algorithm = N'SHA2_256';
SELECT HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x3100), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x0031);
SET @Algorithm = N'SHA2_512';
SELECT HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x3100), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, 0x0031);
```

In Oracle, you should use the `CONVERT` function to get the string into the `AL16UTF16LE` encoding, and then hash that value. That should match up to what SQL Server has. For example, you can see the different encoding forms of [White Bullet (U+25E6)](https://unicode-table.com/en/25E6/) and how using `CONVERT` along with `AL16UTF16LE` will correct this on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7175b659825d2f26d3f8dd0b33e0c307) and below:

```
SELECT DUMP(CHR(14849958), 1016) AS "UTF8",
       DUMP(CHR(9702 USING NCHAR_CS), 1016) AS "UTF16BE",
       DUMP(CONVERT(CHR(9702 USING NCHAR_CS), 'AL16UTF16LE' ), 1016) AS "UTF16LE"
FROM DUAL;

SELECT DUMP('a' || CHR(14849958), 1016) AS "UTF8",
       DUMP('a' || CHR(9702 USING NCHAR_CS), 1016) AS "UTF16BE",
       DUMP(CONVERT('a' || CHR(9702 USING NCHAR_CS), 'AL16UTF16LE' ), 1016) AS "UTF16LE"
FROM DUAL;
```

That returns:

```
UTF8:     Typ=1 Len=3 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: e2,97,a6
UTF16BE:  Typ=1 Len=2 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 25,e6
UTF16LE:  Typ=1 Len=2 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: e6,25


UTF8:     Typ=1 Len=4 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 61,e2,97,a6
UTF16BE:  Typ=1 Len=4 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,61,25,e6
UTF16LE:  Typ=1 Len=4 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 61,0,e6,25
```

As you can see in the 3rd column, the character set is misreported as being Big Endian when it is clearly Little Endian based on the order of the two bytes. You can also see that both characters are two bytes in UTF-16, and the order of *both* of them is different between Big and Little Endian, not just the characters that are > 1 byte in UTF-8.

Given all of this, since the data is being stored as UTF-8 yet you are seeing it as UTF-16 Big Endian via the `DUMP` function, it seems like you are already converting it to UTF-16, but probably not realizing that the default UTF-16 in Oracle is Big Endian.

Looking at the ["UTF-16" definition on the Glossary page of the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/glossary.html#GUID-C0E35C83-AD68-4A7B-BB3B-8A4270F2D274), it states (I broke the following sentences into two parts so it would be easier to distinguish between BE and LE):

> AL16UTF16 implements the big-endian encoding scheme of the UTF-16 encoding form (more significant byte of each code unit comes first in memory). AL16UTF16 is a valid national character set.

and:

> AL16UTF16LE implements the little-endian UTF-16 encoding scheme. It is a conversion-only character set, valid only in character set conversion functions such as SQL `CONVERT` or PL/SQL `UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW`.

P.S. Since you are using `AL32UTF8` in Oracle, you should be using the `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC` collation in SQL Server, not `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. The one you are using is older and doesn't fully support Supplementary Characters (no data loss if they exist, but built-in functions handle them as 2 characters instead of a single entity).

Comment: My question was a little light on details, apologies, but your answer has given me the solution. I was converting to AL16UTF16 but not specifying BE or LE. I had looked into the server settings and it was 'supposed' to be little endian according to what I'd found but specifying AL16UTF16LE in my conversion has now flipped the bytes and my checksum is now matching correctly, thanks for the info on the collation as well.

Comment: @HandyD Glad to hear that it's working now :-) Yeah, AL16UTF16 _is_ Big Endian, which is the default. The only way to get Little Endian in Oracle is to specify that character set explicitly, and it can only be done in the CONVERT function, or a few other similar functions. I updated my answer to include something I had found earlier but forgot to include. It's the quotes from the Oracle doc towards the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is `Little-Endian` encoding that `SQL Server` uses to store `Unicode` characters (more precisely, it uses `UCS-2 LE`).

More on `Little-Endian` here: [Difference between Big Endian and little Endian Byte order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701624/difference-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-byte-order)

I don't know how it was possible that

> When I use DUMP in Oracle or convert to VARBINARY in SQL Server **the
>   data matches exactly except for the bytes for this character**

**All** the `Unicode` characters stored in `SQL Server`, converted to `binary`, are "inverted", I mean, to see the real codes you should divide them in groups of 2 `bytes` and invert the order within every pair.

Example:

```
declare @str varchar(3) = 'abc';
declare @str_n nvarchar(3) = N'abc';

select cast(@str as varbinary(3));
select cast(@str_n as varbinary(6));
```

The result is

```
0x616263

0x610062006300
```

As you see in case of `Unicode` characters bytes are inverted:
"a" is represented as `0x6100` and not as `0x0061`.

The same story is about `0x25E6` that is real `Unicode` code while in `binary` representation in `SQL Server` you see it as `0xE625`, i.e. `inverted`.